# AWS load balancer always routes 443 to 8443

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, load-balancing

I am serving up content on an ec2 instance running tomcat 7.  I have all traffic routing in the tomcat config to 8443 and a valid cert installed.  When i explicitly put https://website.com:443 the site loads fine, but when i put in http://website.com it should route to the https with port 443, but it uses the port 8443 instead.  Anyone have any idea why this would be happening? I have the exact same config working on another server but i have two new servers that dont want to behave.

in my tomcat server.xml i have:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
               sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
               ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
               TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
               TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
               TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
               TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
               keystoreFile="conf/cert.p12"
               keystorePass="password"
               keystoreType="PKCS12" />
```

and in web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
 <web-resource-collection>
 <web-resource-name>Protected Context</web-resource-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </web-resource-collection>
 <!-- auth-constraint goes here if you requre authentication -->
 <user-data-constraint>
 <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
 </user-data-constraint>
 </security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to this, turns out i had to route all traffic over TCP from 8443 to 8443.  The client was requesting port 80, routing to 8080 per my load balancer config for tomcat to serve up content, tomcat was turning the request into requesting port 8443.

8443 wasnt being routed back to 8443 on the tomcat server so it just ended up in a dead end. hope this helps someone else someday.

Comment: If this solves your question, please accept the answer (even if you answered your own question).

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat sends a redirect when using a `transport-guarantee` of `CONFIDENTIAL`

By default this is your connector port. Run a `curl -vs http://website.com` to confirm.

You could set the http/8080 connectors `redirectPort` to `443` but this means you are choosing ELB redirects to work. Local Tomcat redirects will then start failing as nothing listens locally on 443, just the ELB does.